# Excluding row from a MySQL select query based on the contents of another pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following MySQL query...

```
select users.id, group_concat(devices.id) as devicesIds,
  pois.id as poi_id, events.name as event
from `users`
  left join `devices` on `users`.`id` = `devices`.`user_id`
  left join `poi_user` on `users`.`id` = `poi_user`.`user_id`
  left join `pois` on `pois`.`id` = `poi_user`.`poi_id`
  left join `events` on `events`.`poi_id` = `pois`.`id`
  left join `event_user` on `users`.`id` = `event_user`.`user_id`
where (`events`.`startDate` > now())
group by users.id, pois.id, events.name
```

...which simply gets some processed fields from the different joined tables (getting only future events), grouped by several keys.

Now, I need to add an additional constraint so that if there is ***any*** record in the ***event_user*** table related to that particular *user + event* in each case, then that row should not be returned in the main select. Any ideas?

Comment: Move the WHERE condition to the events ON clause.

Comment: The *event_user* table has nothing to do with *users* in this case. I need just an additional constraint to the existing ones...

Comment: Do you want to LEFT JOIN events? Your current query returns INNER JOIN result. If you move the condition, you'll get LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: I want INNER JOIN events, that is fine. But when I execute the query, I need that the users with any *subscribed* event (through *event_user* table) does not come in the results.

Comment: If you want INNER JOIN result, then write INNER JOIN (to avoid future confusion.)

Comment: Could you suggest me the right syntax for it? Or even better, just edit the question accordingly.